# Sharepoint usage per user for page and directory

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, user-profile

Do you know if it's possible to get usage per user for page/directory in SharePoint? (number of page viewed etc...)?

Thanks.

Comment: Foundation, Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: No idea, how can I know it?

Comment: If you paid for it or not :) Check this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj715890.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the Popularity Trends area in Site Settings? There should also be a Popularity Trends button on the ribbon to give you a spreadsheet of visits, etc.

This blog explains a little, and has screenshots of these menu options:

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-analytics